# Error while creating oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I am using oracle 12c on win8 64 and I want to create oracle database through the dbca wizard ,

when I click finish I got the following Error

[image]

It says MYLISTENER already exists Even this is the first time I have create this listener on this port

Any Help

Comment: Check the services - is there already a listener created?  This error might be about the name, not the port.

Comment: did you check that the log file that is mentioned in this error message?